# mysql delete with left join with another table

Tags: mysql

comment table

```
+------+----------+
| id   | comment  | 
+------+----------+
|    1 | foo      |
|    2 | bar      |
|    3 | foobar   |
+------+----------+
```

reply table

```
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | reply   |comment_id  |
+------+----------+------------+
|    1 | nice lol | 1          |
|    2 | ok ok    | 2          |
|    3 | hello    | 1          |
|    4 | hello2   | 1          |
|    5 | hello1   | 1          |
+------+----------+------------+
```

like_reply  table

```
+------+----------+ 
| id   | reply_id | 
+------+----------+  
|    1 |    1     | 
|    2 |    2     | 
|    3 |    3     |  
|    4 |    4     | 
|    5 |    5     |  
+------+----------+ 


 DELETE `comment`,`reply`  FROM `comment` LEFT JOIN `reply`
ON `comment`.`id` = `reply`.`comment_id` WHERE `comment`.`id` = '1'
```

this query must delete comment with id one and all reply with comment_id one

but how can i join the like_reply table and delete all liked reply

the like_replay with relation with reply table by reply id and the reply table with relation with commnet table by comment id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE c, r, lr
FROM `comment` AS c
LEFT JOIN `reply` AS r ON c.id = r.comment_id
LEFT JOIN like_reply AS lr ON r.id = lr.reply_id
WHERE c.id = 1;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b8d1/1)

The above query deletes comment with `id=1` records from `comment` table along with related records in `reply` and `like_reply` tables.

However, if you **always** want the `comment` record deletion to **cascade** to the other tables, then you should consider placing [**foreign key constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in `reply` and `like_reply` tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` subclause..

Answer (score 0):

You can't specific column in delete  ..

```
DELETE FROM `comment` LEFT JOIN `reply`
ON `comment`.`id` = `reply`.`comment_id` WHERE `comment`.`id` = '1'
```

if you want "delete" only some fiedl in a rows you should use update